# Change type of property in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, fastify

I have a multiple routes and i want to check if my response is of some type. For response data i need to use res.data, as it easy to pass data like this between app hooks and plugins. Problem is res.data is defined at top level of app and i don't know how to change it in handler or make generic in top level.

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-river-te9tx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

```
server.route({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/route1",
  handler: async (req, res) => {
    // test1 should give error, because it's not in type Route1Res
    res.data = { res1: "hi", test: 1 };

    // i can do what i want like this, but i need data to be a res prop.
    const data: Route1Res = { res1: "hi" };

    return res.send(res.data);
  }
});
```

Comment: [It does seem to work](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAFwngDgpgBASgewK4igRjlAzjAvDAb2BhgCds0AuGLEUgSwDsBzAbmAF92BjBR2mNwCGAGxEAjIdwDWeGAApyWagQAmQkEOqIU6TFg4BKPAD5CxGAHpLMVLTQ0AFshGqYzegDdYUUqQSkADQw4lDCSFiw9CAA5DiMCCAwTLaQsDqoGNgWSgB06ppyBGQU1ABEjvRlwXYg1A5cwBbWyYJCjDCqCDAA7o4arT3tSSL00rAglVjB4iitjFBQbgVCtt2hMKtKMBD+ELkWvPxJK9rImfpFJVhUMBVVMI05UCBIpB15K+wcwEA) - are you sure your types are resolved correctly?

Comment: Yes, but than res.send() is become missing. Updated example.